# Collation of "E" and "É" in Hungarian, using Perl and Unicode::Collate::Locale

Tags: perl, unicode, multilingual

I have the following test script:

```
#!/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.16/bin/perl

use 5.014_001;
use utf8;
use Unicode::Collate;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;
use Data::Dump;
use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );
use Unicode::Collate::Locale;


binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my @words =("Értékesítési", "Értékesítési", "Érvényes", "EU-s", "Eszközmozgás");

my $coll = Unicode::Collate::Locale->new(locale => "hu");

my @result = $coll->sort(@words);


foreach my $item (@result){
print $item, "\n";
}
```

It outputs:

```
Értékesítési
Értékesítési
Érvényes
Eszközmozgás
EU-s
```

But according to my Hungarian informant, and to Wikipedia "E" comes before "É".
Can someone tell me what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, E comes before É

Comment: Did you tried HU or hu_HU as encoding?

Comment: I've tried hu, hu_HU, and HU, and each time, "EU-s" comes last in the list above. I guess I'm confused, because I thought Hungarian treats É as a separate letter, that should sort after E. So is this a bug in Unicode::Collate::Locale? I wonder what @tchrist thinks? According to this wikipedia page, the two should be treated as separate letters. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_alphabet

Answer (score 2):

Hungarian collation order treats E and É as the same at the primary level, so the results are correct. When two words differ only in the presence or absence of an acute accent, the one without accent comes first, but the primary sort is performed without considering acutes.